# Часть html кода c thymeleaf не отображается

Tags: html, html5, view, thymeleaf

Я пытаюсь создать регистрационную форму. Для этого использую html в связке с thymeleaf. Почему-то после внесения необходимых фрагментов thymeleaf в html, перестала отображаться часть страницы с собственно формой. Вроде всё делаю по туториалу. Много гуглил, нашёл кучу вариантов по улучшению своего кода в других местах, но собственно на решение моего вопроса не напал. Пожалуйста помогите решить вопрос. Когда открываю "просмотреть код" на открытой странице, вижу что в панели отображается сообщение об ошибке - "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()".
Я так понимаю проблема может крыться в серверной части. Хотя я понятия не имею что там может быть не так. Мой spring-контроллер просто выводит представление на экран. Никаких действий внутри не происходит.
Ниже прилагаю отрывок моего кода.
Подскажите пожалуйста что я упускаю и где можно посмотреть. Гуглил много, но не наёл ответ.

```
    <div class="container" id="container-middle">
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="user" type="com.mypath.model.UserDetails"*/-->
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="register-form" method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/post-user-info}"
          th:object="${user}">
        <h2 id="form-header">Sign up for BlaBlaService</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="login" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Login:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" id="login" placeholder="Login" class="form-control" th:field="*{login}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first-name" class="col-sm-5 control-label">First name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="First name" class="form-control"
                       th:field="*{firstName}" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last-name" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Last name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" id="last-name" placeholder="Last name" class="form-control" th:field="*{lastName}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="birthDate" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Date of birth:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="date" id="birthDate" class="form-control" th:field="*{birthDate}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-5">Gender:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{sex}" value="female">Female
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" th:field="*{sex}" value="male">Male
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Кажется решил вопрос. Посмотрел только что и дошло, что я собственно не передал никакой модели на вьюшку чтобы её забайндить результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вставил в котроллер модель в которую можно было бы положить результат заполнения формы. Соответственно оно её и не выводило на экран.

Comment: Вопрос: зачем минусовать, если я сам ответил на свой вопрос, пусть даже ошибка возникла по моему недосмотру?